# How to destructure defaults from a string

Tags: javascript, string, destructuring

I'm wondering how I can destructure default values from a string. For instance, take the following code:

```js
function f({length, valueOf}) {
  console.log("The length is:", length);
  console.log("The string is:", valueOf()); // Expected: "The string is: foo"
}

f("foo");
```

Above, I am trying to get the `length` of the passed in string, as well as the string itself (ie: by calling `valueOf`), however, I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.valueOf requires that 'this' be a
>   String

I was thinking that this was because I can't destructure methods from objects but my testing tells me otherwise:

```js
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  foo: function() {
    return "bar";
  }
}

const {id, foo} = obj;
console.log(id, foo());
```

So, I would like to know two things:

- How can I get the original string passed into my function `f` while destructuing its arguments (is it even possible?)
- Why do I get an error with my first bit of code, but not the other?

Comment: `valueOf ` still needs the string as `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. Once you've destructured a method from an object, you're left with only a reference to the base function, but not the original object (or, in this case, the original string) - without a `this` to extract a value from, the `valueOf` method will not be callable.

For similar reasons, if your `foo` tried to extract a value from the `obj`, it wouldn't work:

```js
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  foo: function() {
    return this.id;
  }
}

const { foo } = obj;
// at this point, without referencing `foo` again, it's impossible to get the `id` of 1
console.log(foo());
```

Your original `foo` works because it does not depend on any calling context - it may as well be just a standalone function.

Note that if you passed an *object* with the string as a property, it would be possible, though you'd have to put the string into a standalone variable, so you may consider it to be cheating:

```js
function f({str: { length, valueOf}, str}) {
  console.log("The length is:", length);
  console.log("The string is:", valueOf.call(str)); // Expected: "The string is: foo"
}

f({ str: "foo" });
```

Comment: And similarly, `function f({length, valueOf(): valueOf}))` doesn't work. Destructuring doesn't allow calling methods. :-) Although that might be a fun thing to experiment with...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This helps clear things up :D

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing todo with destructuring, destructuring is just sugar around variable assignments:

```
  const valueOf = "foo".valueOf;
  valueOf(); // same error

  valueOf.call("other"); // works
```